# Why does wrapping tags around text with Javascript RegEx display the tags as text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to wrap  tags around certain words in a set of links, but the tags are rendering as text.  Why is this, and what can I do to get them to render as HTML?

I have the following Javascript:

```
$('h3 a').each( function(){
    var text = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = text.replace(
        /(^Men\'s|Men’s|Women\'s|Women’s)/g,
        '<span class=\"title\">$1</span>'
    );
});
```

and here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<p><a href="products1.html">Women's Apparel</a></p>
<p><a href="products2.html">Men's Apparel</a></p>
```

My in-browser result is something like:

```
<span class="title">Women's</span> Apparel
<span class="title">Men's</span> Apparel
```

...but obviously I want those spans to be functional elements rather than displaying as text in the browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because you're assigning to `.nodeValue` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either create the DOM nodes yourself, which is tedious, or work with `innerHTML`, which will get parsed and turned into a DOM subtree for you:

```
$('h3 a').each( function(){
    var text = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
    this.innerHTML = text.replace(
        /(^Men\'s|Men’s|Women\'s|Women’s)/g,
        '<span class=\"title\">$1</span>'
    );
});
```

Comment: That makes sense but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"

Comment: Ah, the first child of those `a` is a text node (it cannot have children and cannot have `innerHTML`), so we have to either get the `innerHTML` of `a` itself, or the `nodeValue` of the text node, and set the `innerHTML` of `a` (edited).

Comment: Ah, got it. I have to remove the "firstChild" part since I'm dealing with the innerHTML of the link, not the innerHTML of the link's text.